# Send data to firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm using firebase cloud function to add users to my database after they register.
I want to add (when user is created) a nickname for example.
In the register form, there is a box for nickname, but how can I send it the firebase function so it would be added to the user in the database?

This is firebase function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const ref = admin.database().ref()

exports.createUserAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event=>{
  const uid = event.data.uid
  const email = event.data.email
  const photoUrl = event.data.photoUrl || 'https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/paulblartmallcop/images/9/9c/Person-placeholder-male.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120708210100'

  const newUserRef = ref.child(`/users/${uid}`)
  return newUserRef.set({
    photoUrl: photoUrl,
    email: email,
  })
});
```

The register form is in another file (register.js), how can I send data from there to the function?

I do not call createUserAccount anywhere, it is triggered when this function happens:

```
handlePress = (navigation)=>{
if(this.state.password == this.state.verify){
  firebaseRef.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((newUser)=>{
    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
      ]
    })
    navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
}else{
  //password not match, show error.
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a firebase cloud function to add a nickname to the user (If the user is already created).

Just call from your js :

```
ref.child("users").child(uid).child("nickname").set(nickname);
```

**Other solution**

You can create the user only when the nickname is filled. You can save it in the user.displayName and access to it from your onCreate trigger.

```
exports.createUserAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event=>{
    const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

    const uid = user.uid;
    const email = user.email;
    const nickname = user.displayName;
    const photoUrl = user.photoUrl || 'https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/paulblartmallcop/images/9/9c/Person-placeholder-male.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120708210100';

    const newUserRef = ref.child('/users/${uid}');

    return newUserRef.set({
        nickname: nickname,
        photoUrl: photoUrl,
        email: email
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can I have a an example on the code I provided? I'm new to this and still struggling